# Modelica and state variables

Tags: ode, modelica

Does Modelica transfer the DAE into state-space form (system of ODE's)?

If I want to model a system: For example a simpley model with a dynamic pipe and sink, source: Medium simple incompressible liquid water. What are the state variables (pressure, temperature,..?)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What tool do you use? Dymola? OpenModelica? SimulationX? The used tool (not the language Modelica) choses the state variables and probably all of them can display somehow which variables they have chosen. You can use the annotation `stateSelect` to influence what variables are chosen. http://www.claytex.com/blog/state-selection-overview-and-definitions/

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I use Dymola. But how can I chose state-variables, are they not give through the system-configuaration? For example. Mass-spring system: velocity and position? What would be states in that "pipe, source,sink" example?

Comment: Here is another intersting blog post: http://www.claytex.com/tech-blog/exploring-translation-log-statistics/

Answer (score 1):

Dymola shows the selcted states in the simulation log → Translation tab → Statistics section.
As an example, this is the output for `Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Examples.Oscillator`:

[image: Dymola State Selection]

From the Modelica code, Dymola instantiates all objects, generates flat Modelica code, does some symbolic transformation and simplification (like elimination of alias variables). Then from the remaining variables and equations it chooses the states. How the states are selected and means to influence the selction process are described in the Dymola User Manual Volume 2, section 8.4 "Means to control the selection of states" or in this paper: 
https://www.modelica.org/events/workshop2000/proceedings/old/Mattsson.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A way to do that is to load the `Modelica_LinearSystems2` library and use the function `Modelica_LinearSystems2.ModelAnalysis.Linearize()`.

The `Linearize()` function will return a state space object containing the A, B, C and D matrices but also the input, output and state vectors containing respectively names of the inputs, outputs and states.

If your model is not time-invariant you can also perform a simulation phase before the linearization to retrieve the linearized version of your model at a particular operating point.